# Как создать запрос с группировкой и подсчетом результатов с нескольких таблиц (postgresql sql)

Tags: postgresql, запрос

Есть две таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

надо посчитать общую сумму урона для конкретного парка
Например в таблице contract парк с id 8328 фигурирует два раза, id контракта 743, 513.
Посмотрев таблицу дтп мы видим, что урон составляет: 8124+30159 = 38283

Проблема в том, что я не могу понять как создать такой запрос с нескольких таблиц. таблицы связаны отношением 1:1. но когда я пытаюсь в таблице контракты по id_парк  сгруппировать по id_контракт, чтоб потом в таблице дтп получить данные по урону, у меня постоянно сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
create table contracts (
    id int primary key ,
    client_id int,
    unit_id int,
    park_id int
);

create table crashes (
    event_id int primary key ,
    contact_id int references contracts on update cascade on DELETE restrict ,
    event_date date default current_date,
    damage_amount int
);

insert into contracts (id, client_id, unit_id, park_id)
    values (969, 13, 3, 5532),
           (743, 14, 4, 8328),
           (513, 15, 5, 8328),
           (938, 18, 8, 5421);

insert into crashes (event_id, contact_id, event_date, damage_amount)
    values (11, 969, '2021-03-12', 31909),
           (21, 938, '2021-02-08', 2152),
           (20, 743, '2021-07-03', 8124),
           (14, 513, '2021-08-08', 30159)
;
```

> Ну вот приблизительно в таком виде хочется получать вопросы

##### Ответ

```sql
select park_id, sum(c2.damage_amount)
from contracts c
         join crashes c2 on c.id = c2.contact_id
group by park_id
```

| park_id | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 5421 | 2152 |
| 8328 | 38283 |
| 5532 | 31909 |